# Inequality between linear combinations of rank-one matrices?

Tags: inequality, permutations, matrix-decomposition, majorization

Let $u_1, \cdots, u_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $\|u_i\|_2 \le 1$. Let $a_1, \cdots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. I'm considering a sum of the form
\begin{align*}
S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i u_i^\intercal
\end{align*}
Note that we don't assume $(u_i)$ have any relations among themselves such as orthogonality or anything. Is there any relation we can derive between $S$ and
\begin{align*}
T = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \overline{a} u_i u_i^\intercal
\end{align*}
where $\overline{a} = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$. As in, $S \preceq T$ or $S \succeq T$, or is neither necessarily true?

This problem is currently appearing up in a research problem where the $a_i$'s may possible be allowed to be permuted around to $a_{\sigma(i)}$, and therefore coming up with a uniform bound that is invariant under permutations, such as $\overline{a}$ would be greatly helpful.